# Stop job in pipeline which is running since hours

Tags: azure-devops

I have the problem that a job is running in my azure devOps pipeline which blocks all other upcoming jobs. I have no option to delete it in on the dashboard or something. Maybe someone can help me to cancel or delete the job.

Comment: It's good idea to share more details on what you have. Most likely you have single agent available in your pool and it keeps the rest of the jobs (concurently triggered) in the queue. In order to cancel the run (may be there is infinite loop or something else that keeps agent running the job) you need to click on active run and cancel it. https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_settings/agentqueues - this is the link where you can see all currently running jobs.

Comment: Hi juniordev4life, 
not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Organization Settings->Parallel jobs->click the button View in-progress jobs, then we can see the running job, click the Name to open the pipeline, then we can cancel or delete the running job.

[image]

In addition, if you want to delete or cancel the job, we need related permission.

**Step**: open the pipeline->click the option “…”->enter your account and ensure the permission Delete builds and Stop builds are set to allow, if these permissions are set to Deny, you cannot see the cancel or delete button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove ..\agent\work folder on the agent and that will stop all the running/stuck/deleted jobs.